# Uploading File to FTP Server with node.js requires full directory path to file which isn't available

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ftp

> I am new to js/reactjs/nodejs and I am implementing a feature to allow
> a user to choose a file manually and upload it to a `test local ftp server` (in directory `/test)`. The
> issue i am having is that the `ftp.upload` function takes a `String`
> for the full path of the file being uploaded, but I am not explicitly
> giving the path because the file is chosen via a "Browse files"
> button.
>
> It works perfectly if I test without ftp (locally), but I can't seem
> to upload the file from the request onto a FTP-Server. If I add a full
> path to the file which I want to upload, it seems to work but that ruins the purpose of `choosing a file to upload and uploading after clicking on Upload`

This is the server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const fileUpload = require("express-fileupload");
const app = express();
var EasyFtp = require("easy-ftp");
var ftp = new EasyFtp();

app.use(fileUpload());

var config = {
  host: "127.0.0.1",
  type: "FTP",
  port: "",
  username: "admin",
  password: "",
};

ftp.connect(config);

app.post("/upload", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.files);
  if (req.files === null) {
    return res.status(400).json({ msg: "No file was uploaded" }); //no file uploaded
  }
  const file = req.files.file;

  ftp.upload(file, "/test", function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return res.status(500).send(err);
    } else {
      console.log("finished:", res);
      res.json({ fileName: file.name, filePath: `/upload/${file.name}` });
    }
  });

  //   res.json({ fileName: file.name, filePath: `/uploads/${file.name}` });
});
  ftp.mv(
`/test/(${
  (file.tempFilePath.split("/").at(-1),
  file.name,
  function (err, newPath) {})
})`
  );

ftp.close();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`server started on port ${PORT}`));
```

This is the FileUpload file

```
import React, { Fragment, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import Message from "./Message";
import Progress from "./Progress";

const FileUpload = () => {
  //actual file and filename should go into state because the label "Choose File" needs to be replaced with the actual filename

  const [files, setFile] = useState("");
  const [filename, setFilename] = useState("Choose File...");
  const [uploadedFiles, setUploadedFiles] = useState({});
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
  const [uploadPercent, setUploadPercent] = useState(0);

  const onChange = (e) => {
    setFile(e.target.files[0]);
    let x = [];
    for (let file of e.target.files) {
      x.push(file.name);
    }
    setFilename(x);
  };

  const onSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    //add the file to form data
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", files);
    try {
      const response = await axios.post("/upload", formData, {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        },

        //progress bar for upload
        onUploadProgress: (progressEvent) => {
          setUploadPercent(
            parseInt(
              //get rid of progress bar after 10 seconds of finished upload
              Math.round((progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total)
            )
          );
          setTimeout(() => setUploadPercent(0), 1000);
        },
        //clear loaded percentage bar
      });
      const { fileName, filePath } = response.data;

      setUploadedFiles({ fileName, filePath });
      setMessage("File uploaded successfully");
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.response.status === 500) {
        setMessage("There was a problem with the server, please try again.");
      } else {
        setMessage(error.response.data.msg);
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      {message ? <Message msg={message} /> : null}
      <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <div className="custom-file">
          <input
            type="file"
            className="custom-file-input"
            id="customFile"
            onChange={onChange}
            multiple
          />
          <label className="custom-file-label" htmlFor="customFile">
            {filename}
          </label>
        </div>
        <Progress percentage={uploadPercent} />
        <input
          type="submit"
          value="Upload"
          className="btn btn-primary btn-block mt-4"
        />
      </form>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default FileUpload;
```

Is there any way to correct this? What am I missing? If more code snippets are required please let me know!

### UPDATE!!

---

ftp.mv not doing anything

```
app.post("/upload", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.files);
  if (req.files === null) {
    return res.status(400).json({ msg: "No file was uploaded" }); //error message if no file was uploaded
  }

  const file = req.files.file;
  const tempFileName = file.tempFilePath.split("/").at(-1);

  ftp.upload(file.tempFilePath, "/test", function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return res.status(500).send(err);
    } else {
      console.log("finished:", res);
      res.json({
        fileName: file.name,
        filePath: `/uploads/${file.name}`,
      });
    }
  });
  ftp.mv(`/test/${tempFileName}`, "abc", function (err, newPath) {});
  ftp.close();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending a file to the server, you need to save it momentarily and upload it from there, start by changing your fileUpload configuration to this:

```
    app.use(fileUpload({
      useTempFiles : true,
      tempFileDir : '/tmp/'
    }));
```

Then you can upload the file by accessing its temporary file path:

```
app.post("/upload", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.files);
  if (req.files === null) {
    return res.status(400).json({ msg: "No file was uploaded" }); //no file uploaded
  }
  const file = req.files.file;
  // here we access the temporary file path
  ftp.upload(file.tempFilePath, "/test", function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return res.status(500).send(err);
    } else {
      console.log("finished:", res);
      res.json({ fileName: file.name, filePath: `/upload/${file.name}` });
    }
    ftp.close();
  });

 });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I know seem to get the error `Proxy error: Could not proxy request /upload from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:5000` after changing the variable in ftp.upload. Do you know if this is related to it?

Comment: Where you define your proxy for axios, try to add a forward slash, `http://localhost:5000/`

Comment: unfortunately still the same thing, with the slash. I tried googling about this,, i currently have my npm scripts running concurrently: `"dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""` if this helps

Comment: just to see if it works, could you try to just use http://localhost:5000 in your client axios call?

Comment: ahh that worked! Thatts amazing! Last issue im seeing is that the file was renamed to: `tmp-1-1655998003097`but originally it was a pdf. Is there a way to change this?

Comment: you can use `ftp.mv` to rename the file to the old name

Comment: thanks alot! you just saved my project! Much appreciation Mike!!

Comment: I am trying to implement ftp.mv by using the following:    `ftp.mv(file.tempFilePath, "abc", function (err, newPath) {});` but this seens ti be doing nothing. I am not sure where i need to place it. Is it after the upload? Or is it embedded into the upload? Any help will be really helpful!

Comment: you are uploading at `/test/` in your ftp instance, so do this after upload, ftp.mv(/test/`${file.tempFilePath.split("/").at(-1)`, "abc", function(err, newPath){}};

Comment: please check out my first code block ive updated it to show where im placing the ftp.mv function. I am getting the error message: `Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client` and i have never seen this before but apparantly im writing to header at some point even though it has already been written. Did i place the function at the wrong place? Cheers mike!

Comment: You should place it before the end of the "/upload" route, not out of it.

Comment: Please check the update above, i placed it inside the /upload routing but outside the ftp.upload and yet still its not reacting how it should be. It does nothing currently, but the files are still uploaded. I don’t understand why